# Spherical Pyvista vector plot

Tags: python, vector, pyvista

I'm working on a project on the phases of the moon. On a part of my project, I would like to properly implement an equation (The power output of a star) into pyvista's spherical vector plotting. I am new to pyvista let alone programming in general but the equation should be the same for the x, y and z axes. How would I go about implementing an equation into a pyvista spherical vector plot. Would I just multiply my vector value by the value the equation produces? I also have the values for sigma, T and R to plug into the equation which will produce me a numerical value to work with. The image included is a basic spherical vector plot using pyvista with the luminosity equation provided above. [Basic pyvista sphere vector plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWei0.png)

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what you're asking. You know how to plot a vector field, so you just have to define an appropriate vector field. I don't understand what you mean by "equation into the three axes". At this point this might be more of a math problem than a programming problem. Can you try [edit]ing your question to clarify where you're stuck?

Comment: Regarding your update: it's still not clear to me, sorry. You're talking about power output, but power is a scalar. So it sounds like you have a _scalar_ field defined on a sphere. You would normally plot this as scalars, i.e. colouring the surface of the sphere according to the value of the power. What would the orientation of the arrows represent? Again there's a math step missing: going from your `P(theta, phi)` scalar power to a `V(theta, phi)` vector field. Once you have that, you can plot it with arrows in PyVista.

Comment: What would help is either some psuedo code or some mathemetical descriptions of what you are trying to achieve.  I'm not sure what 'spherical vector plot means'.  Is this a vector plot where each glyphed arrow lies on a sphere but oriented by a vector?